# SwiftUI - Date handling

Tags: swift, date, swiftui

maybe you can help me with following question:

I am programming a UI with two date pickers (startDatePicker and endDatePicker).

The *startDatePicker* should be updated itself to the date of *endDatePicker* in UI when the date of *startEndPicker* is smaller than the date of *endDatePicker*.

Do you habe any idea how I can realise that?

content.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var startDate = Date()
    @State var endDate = Date()
    
    @ObservedObject var dateModel = Period.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            startDatePicker
            endDatePicker
        }
        .onAppear {
//            print("VStack")
//            dateModel.startDate = startDate
//            dateModel.endDate = endDate
            
        }

    }
    
    var startDatePicker: some View{
        
        DatePicker("Start", selection: $startDate, displayedComponents: [.date])
            .datePickerStyle(CompactDatePickerStyle())
            .frame(width: 250, height: 50, alignment: .center)
            .onAppear(perform: {
                print("StartDate.onAppear")
                dateModel.startDate = dateModel.toLocalTime(date: startDate, type: true)
                print(dateModel.startDate)

            })
            .onChange(of: startDate, perform: { startDate in
                print("StartDate.onChange")
                dateModel.startDate = dateModel.toLocalTime(date: startDate, type: true)
                print(dateModel.startDate)
            })
        
    }
    
    var endDatePicker: some View{

        DatePicker("End", selection: $endDate, displayedComponents: [.date])
            .datePickerStyle(CompactDatePickerStyle())
            .frame(width: 250, height: 50, alignment: .center)
            .onAppear(perform: {
                print("EndDate.onAppear")
                dateModel.endDate = dateModel.toLocalTime(date: endDate, type: false)
                print(dateModel.endDate)

            })
            .onChange(of: endDate, perform: { endDate in
                print("EndDate.onChange")
                dateModel.endDate = dateModel.toLocalTime(date: endDate, type: false)

                if dateModel.endDate < dateModel.startDate{
                    print("Error")
                    dateModel.startDate = dateModel.endDate
                }

                print(dateModel.endDate)
            })

    }
}
```

Datahandler.swift

```
class Period  : ObservableObject{
    
    static let shared = Period()
    
    @Published var startDate: Date = Date()
    @Published var endDate: Date = Date()
    
    func toLocalTime(date : Date, type: Bool) -> Date {
        
        var startDate : Date?
        var endDate : Date?
        var dateLocalTimezone : Date?
        

        //Auswahl der aktuellen Kalender
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        
        //Auswahl der Zeitzone
        let timezone = TimeZone.current
        
        //Bestimmen Anzahl Sekunden zwischen Zeitzone und GMT
        let seconds = TimeInterval(timezone.secondsFromGMT(for: date))
        
        //Anpassen des eingelesenen Werts
        if type == true {
            
            startDate = calendar.date(bySettingHour: 00, minute: 00, second: 00, of: date)
            dateLocalTimezone = Date(timeInterval: seconds, since: startDate!)
            
        }else{
            endDate = calendar.date(bySettingHour: 23, minute: 59, second: 00, of: date)
            dateLocalTimezone = Date(timeInterval: seconds, since: endDate!)
        }
        
        return dateLocalTimezone!
    }
    
}
```

Is there a better way for the code? The idea is to separate the part for dates from the UI.

Comment: yes. you are right. this was a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. You can move logic from `onAppeat` to `init()`, and from `.onChange` to `didSet`, like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var dateModel = Period.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            startDatePicker
            endDatePicker
        }
    }
    
    var startDatePicker: some View{
        DatePicker("Start", selection: $dateModel.startDate, displayedComponents: [.date])
            .datePickerStyle(CompactDatePickerStyle())
            .frame(width: 250, height: 50, alignment: .center)
        
    }
    
    var endDatePicker: some View{
        DatePicker("End", selection: $dateModel.endDate, displayedComponents: [.date])
            .datePickerStyle(CompactDatePickerStyle())
            .frame(width: 250, height: 50, alignment: .center)
    }
}

class Period  : ObservableObject{
    
    static let shared = Period()
    
    @Published var startDate: Date {
        didSet {
            let localTime = Self.toLocalTime(date: startDate, type: true)
            if startDate != localTime {
                startDate = localTime
            }
        }
    }
    @Published var endDate: Date {
        didSet {
            let localTime = Self.toLocalTime(date: endDate, type: false)
            if endDate != localTime {
                endDate = localTime
            }
            if endDate < startDate{
                print("Error")
                startDate = endDate
            }
            
            print(endDate)
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        startDate = Self.toLocalTime(date: Date(), type: true)
        endDate = Self.toLocalTime(date: Date(), type: false)
    }
    
    static private func toLocalTime(date : Date, type: Bool) -> Date {
        
        var startDate : Date?
        var endDate : Date?
        var dateLocalTimezone : Date?
        

        //Auswahl der aktuellen Kalender
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        
        //Auswahl der Zeitzone
        let timezone = TimeZone.current
        
        //Bestimmen Anzahl Sekunden zwischen Zeitzone und GMT
        let seconds = TimeInterval(timezone.secondsFromGMT(for: date))
        
        //Anpassen des eingelesenen Werts
        if type == true {
            
            startDate = calendar.date(bySettingHour: 00, minute: 00, second: 00, of: date)
            dateLocalTimezone = Date(timeInterval: seconds, since: startDate!)
            
        }else{
            endDate = calendar.date(bySettingHour: 23, minute: 59, second: 00, of: date)
            dateLocalTimezone = Date(timeInterval: seconds, since: endDate!)
        }
        
        return dateLocalTimezone!
    }
    
}
```

Your `toLocalTime` returns wrong value for end date, like I pass `2021-08-18 23:59:00 +0000` and the result is `2021-08-19 23:59:00 +0000` which is the next day. This proceeds to recursion of `didSet`, but I'll leave fixing this logic to your

Comment: This solution works fine. I don't understand why didSet is recursive?!

Comment: @JorgeReich because inside didSet you're updating incoming value with `toLocalTime` and setting it again, which calls didSet one more time. You could use set/get to prevent that, but in this case you'd have to declare one more variable where you gonna store value for each date, and I find it redundant because just fixing `toLocalTime` will be enough

Comment: dumb question: why are you using static functions? Is that because of the computed properties?

Comment: @JorgeReich No, it's because I don't wanna add default values to properties, and class function cannot be run until all properties are initialized. Also it's a good marker to know that function doesn't modify any class propertied when you troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good fit for SO to ask for "a better way", since every solution has its pros and cons and thus there are a lot of opinions. But the latter I guess, is pretty much consolidated (which is in itself highly opinionated  ;) )

I would like to add some refactoring suggestions:

You can make the DatePickerView a reusable component:

```
    struct DatePickerView: View {
        let title: String
        let date: Date
        let setDateAction: (Date) -> Void

        var body: some View {
            let binding: Binding<Date> = .init {
                return self.date
            } set: { newValue in
                self.setDateAction(newValue)
            }

            DatePicker(title, selection: binding, displayedComponents: [.date])
                .datePickerStyle(CompactDatePickerStyle())
        }
    }
```

Then, it can be used in the ContentView as follows:

```
    struct ContentView: View {
        let state: TwoDatePickers.ViewModel.ViewState
        let setStartDate: (Date) -> ()
        let setEndDate: (Date) -> ()

        var body: some View {
            VStack{
                Text("Start: \(state.startDate)")
                    .padding()
                Text("End: \(state.endDate)")
                    .padding()
                DatePickerView(
                    title: "Start",
                    date: state.startDate,
                    setDateAction: self.setStartDate)
                .padding()

                DatePickerView(
                    title: "End",
                    date: state.endDate,
                    setDateAction: self.setEndDate)
                    .padding()
            }
        }
    }
```

You might notice that ContentView has no coupling to any certain kind of view model or model, and no logic what so ever. That's by intention to make it reusable as well and let the logic be done elsewhere.

Now, you can implement your view model plus logic as a separated component as well. I am cheating here a bit, since it internally uses a reusable "store" component ;)

```
extension TwoDatePickers {

    static let store = Oak.Store(state: .init(),
                    update: update,
                    scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)


    final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        typealias ViewState = TwoDatePickers.State

        init() {
            cancellableState = store.sink { state in
                self.viewState = self.view(state)
            }
        }

        @Published
        private(set) var viewState: ViewState = .init()

        private var cancellableState: AnyCancellable!

        private func view(_ state: State) -> ViewState { state }

        func setStartDate(_ date: Date) {
            store.input.send(.setStartDate(date))
        }

        func setEndDate(_ date: Date) {
            store.input.send(.setEndDate(date))
        }
    }
}
```

Note, that the ViewModel is just a thin wrapper which connects the store and provides a `view` function which returns a ViewState from the store's state. The ViewState is the thing that completely and unambiguously defines what the view should render, while the store's State is there to perform the logic and may contain additional data. That is, ViewState is a function of State.

The "store" is implemented much like in Redux or Elm, which can be done in a few lines of code.

As mentioned, this is also a reusable component. It is event driven, unidirectional and uses internally a Finite State Machine to change state and generate outputs.

So, you have to implement an `update` function, which is basically the heart of your logic:

```
extension TwoDatePickers {
    struct State {
        var startDate: Date = Date()
        var endDate: Date = Date()
    }

    enum Event {
        case setStartDate(Date)
        case setEndDate(Date)
    }

    typealias Command = Void

    static func update(state: State, setter: (State) -> Void, event: Event) -> Void {
        switch (state, event) {
        case (_, .setStartDate(let date)):
            let adjustedEndDate = Date(
                timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: max(
                    date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate,
                    state.endDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate))

            setter(State(startDate: date, endDate: adjustedEndDate))

        case (_, .setEndDate(let date)):
            let adjustedStartDate = Date(
                timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: min(
                    date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate,
                    state.startDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate))

            setter(State(startDate: adjustedStartDate, endDate: date))

        default:
            print("not handled: \(state), \(event)")
            break
        }
    }

}
```

To wire all the things together, we may use a "root view". Here you can see how eventually the view model gets connected to the views:

```
struct TwoDatePickersSceneView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = TwoDatePickers.ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        TwoDatePickers.ContentView(
            state: viewModel.viewState,
            setStartDate: viewModel.setStartDate,
            setEndDate: viewModel.setEndDate
        )
    }

}
```

What's left is the reusable implementation of the store. I post it here as a bonus:
https://gist.github.com/couchdeveloper/4100f1ec8470980c5c49adc119240de1

Final note:

This is an example how we can decompose a typical SwiftUI feature and separate it into several reusable components. You don't have to do this extra effort when the feature is small and tidy. However, this solution, especially using a Finite State Machine to solve UI problems scales much better for more complex problems.